# how to cite the numeric reference at beginning of sentence

Tags: bibtex, citing, elsarticle

I want to citing the numeric references using BibTeX. Problem arise when I try to cite a reference at the beginning of a sentence. e.g., when I try to cite \citet{TrHe02} at the beginning of sentence the I got "(author?)[1]". Actually the citation should be "Trampert and Heijst [1]". But when I cite the same at end or inbetween the sentence using "citep" or "cite" then I got citation correctly as "[1]". How to get the correct citation as "Trampert and Heijst [1]" at he beginning of sentence?. Below I have given my latex script with content of reference file and file which i have used inside script with the link.

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}

\begin{document}


\section{Introduction}

\citet{TrHe02}, when I use "citet" then i get the problem, but if cite it as ''citep'' or ''cite'' then i just got the numeric reference. 

\cite{TrHe02}, here i used just use cite at the beginning i just got the numeric reference as [1]. Actually i should get as  Trampert and Heijst \citep{TrHe02}. I have manually written Trampert and Heijst.
```

From here details of the file which i have use while running the script.

```
In the latex script all this file elsarticle and elasrticle-num are standard which i have taken from website. This is the link

\verb+http://www.elsevier.com/author-schemas/the-elsarticle-latex-document-class+

And the file to be download is elsarticle.zip
I am using elsarticle-template-num.tex, elsarticle-num.bst and 
elsarticle.cls
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
\bibliography{refs}
\end{document}
```

% refs.bib is my reference file and it contain

```
 @STRING{SCI={Science}} 

@article{TrHe02, 
 AUTHOR ={Trampert, J. and Heijst, H. J. V.}, 
 TITLE  ={Global Azimuthal Anisotropy in the Transition Zone}, 
 YEAR ={2002}, 
 JOURNAL    =SCI, 
 VOLUME={296}, 
 NUMBER={}, 
 MONTH  ={}, 
 PAGES  ={1297-1299} 
}
```

Comment: Please update the question instead of addin additional informaion as a comment

Comment: Please read the content inside the introduction to understand the my problem.

Comment: And make your MWE into a single example, not two (that makes it easier to get people to help).

Answer (score 1):

Have a closer read of that Elsevier page, you need to use `elsarticle-num-names` not `elsarticle-num`

Comment: Thanks, Ya it should be elsarticle-num-names. In elsarticle-template-num.tex it was mention elsarticle-num, so i did not use elsarticle-num-names.